# Replacing a function in Websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

How can I change the echo function after connecting the client to the server?

```
import asyncio
from websockets import serve

async def echo(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

async def main():
    async with serve(echo, "localhost", 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Barmar 
Replace with another function

Comment: You can do `echo = some_other_function`

Comment: @Barmar Is it possible to do this with functions ? Assign another function to the name of one function ?